# Deny access to specific files for specific users

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization

I have two users on my website, User `A` and User `B`. And I have two files File `One` and File `Two`. I want only `A` to access file `One` and only `B` to access File `Two`. How can I make this happen in Asp.Net . I know that I can use web.config way as follows

```
    <authorization>
    <allow users="user1, user2"/>
    <deny users=”?”/>
   </authorization>
```

But my users and files are created dynamically so I can't go to web.config each time and change the users. Is there any other way to achieve this? Maybe programmatically?

> Note: Here the files are media files like image or pdf

Comment: do files mean web files like : html, aspx etc ?

Comment: @tharif nop, Media files like PDF

Comment: why going for web config, you can set access rights based on logged user type !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go the route of the Web.config you will need to look at creating your own handler or similar process to intercept the content and apply your security rules to things.

Handlers are mapped by a specific file path, so you can override for a specific root path and file type if needed.  But you will have to process secure and unsecured items.

THe exact implementation is a bit more involved than I can quickly post here.  However, [this article](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2009/11/11/securing-pdf-files-in-asp-net-with-custom-http-handlers/) walks through the steps/

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this code in Web.config

<location path="One.aspx">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="A"/> 
// allow John ..note: you can have multiple users seperated by comma e.g. John,Mary,etc

<deny users="*"/>  // deny others
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

<location path="Two.aspx">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="B"/> 
// allow John ..note: you can have multiple users seperated by comma e.g. 
 // John,Mary,etc

<deny users="*"/>  // deny others
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```